# Issue with Updating Attendance Records in Django using MySQL

Tags: python, django, time-and-attendance

I am encountering an issue with updating attendance records in my Django application using MySQL. I have a handle_attendance_record function intended to update or create an AttendanceRecord for an employee based on check-in and check-out logs. However, the records are not updating as expected.

Here is the code for my function:

```py
from datetime import datetime

class AttendanceRecord(models.Model):
    # Model definition
    ...

def handle_attendance_record(self, log_data, log_time):
    user_id = str(log_data["UserId"]).zfill(4)
    try:
        employee = Employee.objects.get(employee_matricule=user_id)
    except Employee.DoesNotExist:
        print(f"Employee not found for user_id {user_id}")
        return

    log_date = log_time.date()
    record, created = AttendanceRecord.objects.get_or_create(
        employee=employee, date=log_date, defaults={'check_in': None, 'check_out': None})

    if log_data["Type"] == "CheckOut" and record.check_out is None:
        record.check_out = log_time.time()
    elif log_data["Type"] == "CheckIn" and record.check_in is None:
        record.check_in = log_time.time()

    if record.check_in and record.check_out:
        record.working_hours = datetime.combine(log_date, record.check_out) - datetime.combine(log_date, record.check_in)

    record.save()
```

And here is a snippet of the data from my MySQL database:

```
mysql> select * from ap_attendancelog;
+----+----------+------------+------------+
| id | user_id  | log_type   | log_time   |
+----+----------+------------+--------------------+
|  1 | 0004     | CheckIn    | 2023-12-19 11:15:08|
|  2 | 0004     | CheckOut   | 2023-12-19 21:15:08|
+----+----------+------------+--------------------+
 
mysql> select * from ap_attendancerecord;
+----+------------+-----------+-----------+
| id | employee_id| check_in  | check_out |
+----+------------+-----------+-----------+
|  1 | 0004       | 11:15:08  | NULL      |
+----+------------+-----------+-----------+
```

Comment: Is `handle_attendance_record()` called anywhere?